# Getting specific SQL Commands from DataAdapter.Update with parameters

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, audit, oledbdataadapter

I'm trying to improve the current auditing I have with one of my databases. Currently this is done with access data macro's however I use vb.net as a front end.

Most of the updates use a data adapter and use the following command to update the backend

```
CurrentDataAdapter.Update
```

For the purposes of inserting the information into an audit table I would like to be able to list the SQL commands that take place with this. Using the command text just gives a single SQL command with the parameters place holders

```
CurrentDataAdapter.UpdateCommand.CommandText
```

Gives

> UPDATE [Table] Set F1=@P1 WHERE ID=@P2

However I'm more after a list of

> - UPDATE [Table] SET F1=a WHERE ID=1
> - UPDATE [Table] Set F2=b WHERE ID=2
> - UPDATE [Table] SET F3=c WHERE ID=3

Is this possible? (Multiple SQL statements in one are not supported with Access backend)

Many thanks

Comment: Iterate through the CurrentDataAdapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters collection?

Comment: Wouldn't that be a way of listing the parameters; i.e. P1, P2 etc?

Comment: ...  and the values of those parameters. Then those values could be recombined with the UpdateCommand SQL to rebuild the text. Isn't that the OP? I took a shot. ;)

Comment: I had a quick play with it and can get the values; I could do a replace on the command text to get a series of string like I want but looping through the parameters only seems to do it for a single record.

I could perhaps do it from looping through the dataset; I just thought there must be an easier method using the adapter & parameters